# Cannot pass props from Laravel blade file to Vue Component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to pass value from Laravel to Vue. But the props I get is always undefined (from console.log). I checked it's not the camel case issue. I really can't find where is the issue. Can anyone help, please?
PS. I'm a laravel and Vue beginner. Thank you very much

blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.subject')

@section('content')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/subject/subjectapp.js') }}" defer></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <sample message="HELLO"></sample>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

subjectapp.js file:

```
require('../bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');


import 'babel-polyfill'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Sample from '../components/subject/Sample.vue';

Vue.use(Vuetify);


const sample = new Vue({
    el: 'sample',

    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
        Sample
    },
    render: h => h(Sample),

});
```

Sample.vue file

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col border m-2">
                MESSAGE
                {{message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

        props: ['message'],

        created() {
            console.log(this.message);
        },

    }
</script>
```

Edit:
extra info of my app:

data CANNOT be passed from blade.php to a vue component(A.vue) nested inside.

Data CAN be passed from a Vue component(A.vue) nested in the blade.php, to a vue component(B.vue) nested in that component(A.vue).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the end of your `blade.php` file

```
<script>
  window.prop1 = somePropValue;
  window.prop2 = somePropValue;
</script>
```

and access it on your `vue` file by calling `window.prop1`

This solution works for me. Here are my files:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <main class="py-sm-4">
      <chat-component @if(isset($create_message)) user="{{ $create_message }}" @endif></chat-component>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
    'auth' => auth() -> check() ? auth() -> user() -> id : null,
  ])!!};

  window.LaravelUrl = "{{ url('') }}"
  window.user_id = "{{Auth::id()}}"
</script>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import WebRTC from 'vue-webrtc'; //video call plugin, not relevant to the answer

Vue.use(WebRTC); //video call plugin, not relevant to the answer

Vue.component('chat-component', require('./components/ChatComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

Vue example usages:

```
axios.post(window.LaravelUrl + `/send/${this.friend.session.id}`)
//
axios.post(window.LaravelUrl + "/send_calling_info", {
    session_id: this.friend.session.id,
    receiver_id: this.friend.id,
    caller_id: window.user_id
})
//
return this.session.blocked_by == window.Laravel.auth;
```

and some other usages inside `axios.post()`

Comment: sorry I don't get it. How do you call it in the vue file? Thank you

Comment: It is global you can call it as you defined in your `blade.php` file. Like `window.propName`. Did you try it, did it not work?

Comment: I tried but it says it's not defined. And is this the correct way to pass props from blade to vue? I have to use a global variable? How come <sample message="HELLO"></sample> does not work?

Comment: I have a `messages.blade.php` and it works for me. I will add my files to answer maybe that would help you.

Comment: thanks. but I finally found out what went wrong with my code. In my app.js file, I was using "sample" as the el. But I actually should use the div#app  in my layouts.subject instead. Now I can pass data in  <sample message="HELLO"></sample>  this format.